# Core Data — Find-or-Create Efficiently

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, optimization, time

According to Apple's documentation([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdimporting.html))—

> There are many situations where you may need to find existing objects
>   (objects already saved in a store) for a set of discrete input values.
>   A simple solution is to create a loop, then for each value in turn
>   execute a fetch to determine whether there is a matching persisted
>   object and so on. This pattern does not scale well. If you profile
>   your application with this pattern, you typically find the fetch to be
>   one of the more expensive operations in the loop (compared to just
>   iterating over a collection of items). Even worse, this pattern turns
>   an `O(n)` problem into an `O(n^2)` problem.
>
> It is much more efficient—when possible—to create all the managed
>   objects in a single pass, and then fix up any relationships in a
>   second pass. For example, if you import data that you know does not
>   contain any duplicates (say because your initial data set is empty),
>   you can just create managed objects to represent your data and not do
>   any searches at all. Or if you import "flat" data with no
>   relationships, you can create managed objects for the entire set and
>   weed out (delete) any duplicates before save using a single large `IN`
>   predicate.

**Question 1:** Considering that my data I'm importing doesn't have any relationships, how do I implement what is described in the last line.

> If you do need to follow a find-or-create pattern—say because you're
>   importing heterogeneous data where relationship information is mixed
>   in with attribute information—you can optimize how you find existing
>   objects by reducing to a minimum the number of fetches you execute.
>   How to accomplish this depends on the amount of reference data you
>   have to work with. If you are importing 100 potential new objects, and
>   only have 2000 in your database, fetching all of the existing and
>   caching them may not represent a significant penalty (especially if
>   you have to perform the operation more than once). However, if you
>   have 100,000 items in your database, the memory pressure of keeping
>   those cached may be prohibitive.
>
> You can use a combination of an IN predicate and sorting to reduce
>   your use of Core Data to a single fetch request.

Example code:

```
// Get the names to parse in sorted order.
NSArray *employeeIDs = [[listOfIDsAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]
        sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];

// create the fetch request to get all Employees matching the IDs
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:
        [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:aMOC]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(employeeID IN %@)", employeeIDs]];

// Make sure the results are sorted as well.
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:
    @[ [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"employeeID" ascending:YES] ]];
// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error;
NSArray *employeesMatchingNames = [aMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

> You end up with two sorted arrays—one with the employee IDs passed
>   into the fetch request, and one with the managed objects that matched
>   them. To process them, you walk the sorted lists following these
>   steps:
>
> Get the next ID and Employee. If the ID doesn't match the Employee ID,
>   create a new Employee for that ID. Get the next Employee: if the IDs
>   match, move to the next ID and Employee.

**Question 2:** In the above example, I get two sorted arrays as described above. Considering the worst case scenario where all the objects that are to be inserted are present in the store, I don't see anyway that I can solve the problem in `O(n)` time. Apple describes the two steps as above but that is an `O(n^2)` job. For any `kth` element in the input array, there might or might not exist an element that matches it in the first `k` elements in the output array. So in the worst case, the complexity will be `O(nC2) = O(n^2)`.

So, what I believe Apple is doing is making sure that fetch only processes once even though there are `O(n^2)` checks required. If so, then I'll go with this; but is there any other way of doing this efficiently.

Please understand, that I don't want to fetch again and again - fetch once for an input array of size 100 identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ad. 1** The fact of having relationships isn't important here. This explanation only says that if you download your data from e.g. a remote server and your items have some IDs, then you can fetch them all from the persistent store in one request, instead of fetching each object in a separate request.

**Ad. 2**

> Apple describes the two steps as above but that is an O(n^2) job.

It's not. Please read these lines carefully:

> To process them, you walk the sorted lists following these steps:
>
> Get the next ID and Employee. If the ID doesn't match the Employee ID,
>   create a new Employee for that ID. Get the next Employee: if the IDs
>   match, move to the next ID and Employee.

You walk the arrays/lists simultaneously, so you never have to make this check: "there might or might not exist an element that matches it in **the first k elements in the output array**." You don't need to check previous elements as they're sorted and they certainly won't contain the object you're interested in.

Comment: Ok I understand that and I was wrong. It's basically an O(n) process. But that still leaves part 1. How does one accomplish this —

> Or if you import "flat" data with no relationships, you can create managed objects for the entire set and weed out (delete) any duplicates before save using a single large IN predicate.

Comment: @flippex17: I think what they mean is this. You insert managed objects into a context. Then you grab IDs (or other identifiers) of these objects, put them into `IN` predicate and fetch array of the objects from the persistent store (objects that you've just inserted won't be fetched, because they're not yet saved). Then you iterate through `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `insertedObjects` and delete objects that were found in the persistent store. It's basically what I wrote in my answer, just implemented in the different order.

Comment: @flippex17: It didn't fit in my previous comment: you also have to convert the array (`fetch array of the objects`) into an `NSDictionary` indexed by your `IDs` to get amortized O(1) lookup.

Comment: When you say fetch array, you mean something like this:     NSArray *matches = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

I am not a pro, but I am just wondering how would one convert this to NSDictionary indexed by IDs given `testID` is one of the fields of the managed Object of type `ATest`. Sorry if this is an easy question but something I am unable to solve.

Comment: @flippex17: yes, that's what I meant by `fetching an array`. You can get `NSDictionary` like this: `NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (ATest *test in matches) {
        mutableDict[test.testID] = test;
    }`

Comment: Got it. I did the same but I was wondering you had a better solution. I am research KVC/KVO methods right now which do the job much better. But yes, this will result in amortized O(1) lookup. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the original Apple documentation there is snapshot here:

http://web.archive.org/web/20150908024050/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdimporting.html